# Black hole image

Tags: black-holes, astronomy, event-horizon, telescopes

We all have seen the official release of the image of the black hole.

scientists took the image of a supermassive black hole at the center of M87,  which is very supermassive but 55 M light year away.

why they don't take the image of the black hole at some nearby galaxy's black hole. There is obviously Andromeda.

In the first place, the question arises why the don't choose a stellar black hole and why black hole at the center of galaxy despite that galactic center might obstruct the visible light due to more and more matter.

Dosen't near by black hole would have gave a better picture?

Comment: Hi Kunal kumar, Have you for starters tried to estimate the angular size of the astronomical objects you suggest?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/409/123208

Comment: That question is related (but certainly *not* a duplicate) because it asks about ways to detect black holes. It's hard to see a black hole if it doesn't have an [accretion disk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accretion_disk).

Comment: agreed by your reasoning

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why couldn't they take pictures of a closer black hole?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/471920/why-couldnt-they-take-pictures-of-a-closer-black-hole) also https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/471792/why-was-m87-targeted-for-the-event-horizon-telescope-instead-of-sagittarius-a

Answer (score 0):

Because not all black holes are located in galaxies that face us head-on. It's not that easy to take a picture of a black hole when it's behind lightyears of stars, dust etc. M87 happened to be facing us head-on, which is why we could take a picture of it. I'm not sure how it was for Saggitarius A* but it must have been something similar.

Answer (score 0):

They chose M87 because it was the black hole that should have had the largest *angular size* as viewed from the Earth. It was also a very massive black hole and the long characteristic timescale for variations in the accretion around it mean that many images, taken over several days, could be co-added to produce a clearer final result.

Details:

The linear size of the expected "black hole shadow" is a small multiple of its Schwarzschild radius, which in turn is proportional to its mass. The angular size in radians is then found by dividing this by the distance to the black hole.

Given a telescope with a fixed angular resolution, you get the best image for an object with the largest angular size. When you compare $r_s/d$ for the various candidate black holes, you find that the one in M87 gives the largest value - it is much further away than Andromeda, but *much* more massive. The black hole shadow in Andromeda is predicted to be about half the angular size of the one in M87.

The only black hole with comparable angular size is the one at the centre of the Milky Way - much less massive, but much closer. An image of this black hole *has* been published since your question was asked. This image is not as good as the one for M87 because the image is less "stable". The timescale for changes in the accretion environment around a black hole is of order $r_s/c$. This is days for the black hole in M87, but minutes for the black hole in the Milky Way. The longer timescale in M87 makes it easier to co-add images taken over several days. For the Milky Way black hole, special techniques had to be developed to pick out the persistent features from a rapidly varying set of images.

The nearest known stellar black holes are thousands of light years away but a billion times less massive than the M87 black hole. Their angular sizes would be *ten thousand times smaller*, so they would not be resolved by the EHT. Their images would also be varying on timescales of milli-seconds, which means there is no possibility of producing a stable image.